# is it possible to force a go routine to be run on a specific CPU?

Tags: go, runtime

I am reading about the go package "runtime" and see that i can among other (func GOMAXPROCS(n int)) set the number of CPU units that can be used to run my program. Can I force a goroutine to be run on a specific CPU of my choice?

Comment: FWIW go 1.5 is said to have a "smarter scheduler" that CPU's more accurately to avoid cache misses going between go routines.  I guess that's kind of like CPU affinity...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In modern Go, I wouldn't lock goroutines to threads for efficiency. Go 1.5 [added goroutine scheduling affinity, to minimize how often goroutines switch between OS threads](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1At2Ls5_fhJQ59kDK2DFVhFu3g5mATSXqqV5QrxinasI/edit). And any cost of the remaining migrations between CPUs has to be weighed against the benefit of the user-mode scheduler avoiding context switches into kernel mode. Finally, when switching costs are a real problem, sometimes a better focus is changing your program logic so it needs to switch less, like by communicating batches of work instead of individual work items.

But even considering all that, sometimes you simply have to lock a goroutine, like when a C API requires it, and I'll assume that's the case below.

---

If the whole program runs with `GOMAXPROCS=1`, then [it's relatively simple to set a CPU affinity by calling out to the taskset utility from the schedutils package](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/setting-processor-affinity-certain-task-or-process.html).

I had thought you were out of luck if `GOMAXPROCS > 1` because then [goroutines are migrated between OS threads at runtime](http://golang.org/doc/faq#goroutines). In fact, James Henstridge points out you can use  [`runtime.LockOSThread()`](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#LockOSThread) to keep your goroutine from migrating.

That doesn't solve locking the OS thread to a CPU. @yerden points out in a comment that [the `SchedSeatffinity` function in the `golang.org/x/sys/unix` package](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/unix#SchedSetaffinity), using 0 as the pid, ought to lock the calling thread to its current CPU.

In the "C API requires locking" use case, it might also work to call [`pthread_setaffinity_np`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_getaffinity_np.3.html) from C code.

I haven't tested either of those ways to lock threads to CPUs, and details will vary by OS there.

Comment: You can lock a goroutine to a particular OS thread with `runtime.LockOSThread` though.  That could be used together with the underlying OS CPU affinity routines to achieve the goal.

Comment: An update here, [golang.org/x/sys/unix](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/unix) package provides SchedSetaffinity function which may be used to pin specified thread to CPU's logical core.

Comment: See also https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11243

Answer (score 3):

Depends on your workload, but sometimes it's beneficial to start a go process per CPU, set gomaxprocs to 1 and pin the process to the CPU with taskset. Here is an excerpt on that topic from the awesome fasthttp library:

> - Use [reuseport](https://godoc.org/github.com/valyala/fasthttp/reuseport)
>     listener.
> - Run a separate server instance per CPU core with GOMAXPROCS=1.
> - Pin each server instance to a separate CPU core using [taskset](http://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset).
> - Ensure the interrupts of multiqueue network card are evenly distributed between CPU cores.   See [this
>     article](https://blog.cloudflare.com/how-to-achieve-low-latency/) for
>     details.
> - Use Go 1.6 as it provides some considerable performance improvements.

Source: https://github.com/valyala/fasthttp#performance-optimization-tips-for-multi-core-systems